# SwiftUI - Animate height of rectangle from 0 to height

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am attempting to animate the height of a `RoundedRectangle()` from 0 to its new height, I would like it to grow from its current position upwards when my device shakes. As it currently stands, I have a `onShake` function which I want to activate the growing of the rectangle.

```
struct View1: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            Text("Hola")
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .font(.headline)
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 0, alignment: .center)
                .foregroundColor(Color("RedColour"))
                .onShake {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can probably tell I am very new to SwiftUI and have very limited knowledge of how animations work. Feel free to grill me for it, but I would also love some help with attempting to grow this rectangle upwards when my device shakes.

Much love!

Comment: You can't set the modifiers directly `frame` is a modifier. Create an `@State` for `height`

Comment: Does this answer your question https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/Answers/Change_rectangle_height_onShake.md?

Comment: Not quite, I need it to animate from the bottom upwards, not from the middle and in both directions. Any possible way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this. But as the information you provided do not include how you want to use this, this might be incomplete.

```
struct View1: View {
    @State private var height: CGFloat = 0 // add this to modify 
                                           // the height of the Rounded Rectangle
    let targetHeight: CGFloat = 100 // targetHeight var to syncronise with the VStack
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            Text("Hola")
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .font(.headline)
                .background{
                    VStack{
                        Spacer(minLength: 0)
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                            .frame(width: 100, height: height)
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                            .onShake {
                                withAnimation(.linear(duration: 5)) {
                                    height = targetHeight
                                }
                            }
                    }.frame(height: targetHeight) // VStack with fixed height
                                                  //to animate from bottom up
                }
        }
    }
}
```